# Signed Measure equivalent definition

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure, define
$$
|\mu|(E) = \mu^+(E) +\mu^-(E)
$$
Why is it that
$$
|{\mu}|(E) = \text{sup}\sum_{k=1}^n|\mu(E_k)|,
$$
where the supremum is taken over all finite disjoint families $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^n$ of measurable subsets of $X$.

Comment: Do you know the Hahn decomposition theorem?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out.